# EJBException NoResultException at login page

Tags: java, ejb

I developed a web in to login from a login.xhtml but I have issues navigating when it validates a user doesn't exist. Rather the page brings out an exception (EJB NoResultException ,getsingle Result()). The application navigates fine when I type the right username and password but it brings the exception page when the user doesn't exist.I am simply trying to achieve that when a user types a wrong password,he is been redirected to the login.xhtml.my code looks like 
This

```
//managed bean class
//session scoped

 private Admin ad = new Admin();
 private String username;
 private String password;
  //string setters getters

   // admin getters, setters

   public String login(){
   ad=  adminEJB.verifyUser(                                  
   username,password);
   If(ad!=null)
   return="welcome";
   else return ="login"; 


}
```

When I login in with the right username and password ,it navigates to the welcome.xhtml page perfectly but when I test it with a wrong password,it shows me the error page Ejb  noresult exception. What could possibly be the problem, I want it to display the login page with a message to say wrong password or invalid account. Also is the idea of using a managedbean to login as sessionscoped the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seeems that your EJB thorws exception if its incorrect login , you may need to catch this exception and return failure.

```
private UIComponent component;

    public UIComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(UIComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }


           public String login(){

        try{
           ad=  adminEJB.verifyUser(                                  
           username,password);
           If(ad!=null)
              return="welcome";
           else {               
          FacesContext context = FacesContext.
               getCurrentInstance();
          context.addMessage(component.getClientId(),
              new FacesMessage("Login Failed")); 
          return "login";
         }

        }catch(EJBException e){
          FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          context.addMessage(component.getClientId(),
            new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));                                                                       return "login";
         }
      }
```

Then use `<h:message>` in your login page to display Login error.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
        >

        <h:body>

            <h:form>
             <h:message for="login"/>
                <h:commandButton id="login" 
 value="click me" action="#{componentMsgBean.doAction}" 
binding="#{componentMsgBean.component}" />
            </h:form>

        </h:body>
    </html>
```

Session Beans are a good idea for Login as you can hold the username and other relevant data like roles etc in user session and access it from any xhtml page . Also as it happens once every user session it makes sense to keep it in session scope.

Comment: Thanks guyz a lot,it was a very simple problem. I just needed to try catch the getSingleResult method in the EJB method, is there away to report with a message on the index page that the password or account is invalid? I was thinkin if converters or message does that

Comment: I have edited  my answer , you can add a binding t your login command and show the failure messages by adding it in login method

Comment: Thanks Mr Avinash,that solved my problems.I got a couple more questions. I want to login with a <h:selectonemenu> as part of a login parameter, like for example login as an admin or a staff,how do I implement this as I have to set the inputtext expression language as #{admincontroller.username} for username and #{admincontroller.password} for password, if a staff wants to login how do I do this? I don't want to have 2 login fields on the page,is there a way the selectonemenu listener can notice a change in the profile and accept the expression language as #{staffcontroller.username} e.t.c

Comment: It is better if you keep selectonemenu in the form and call the single action method , you can check the value of variable in your action and call the staff controller , adminvontrollr method from there

Comment: Please mark it as answered and post the new question, it is useful to keep unanswered questions at top